# select from table using an specific row values

Tags: php, sql, database

basically i want to select rows base of specific row values .
for example i have a table look like this :

```
id   name    sport      score    gender
1    tom     tennis      5       male
2    mia     football    9       male  
3    maria   tennis      7       male
4    liam    swimming    8       female
```

i had try this php script:

```
$query = "select sport , score , gender from sprot_table where id = 1" ;
$res = $con->query($query) ;
$data = $res->fetch_assoc() ;
$sport = $data['sport']  ; $sport = $data['score']  ; $sport = $data['gender']  ; 
$query = "select id , name from sport_table where sport = $sport and gender = $gender and score > $score" ;
$con->query($query) ;
```

and also tried this sql code :

```
select 
     id , name 
from sport_table where 
sport = ( select sport form sport_table where id = 1 ) and 
gender = ( select gender form sport_table where id = 1 ) and 
score > ( select score form sport_table where id = 1 )
```

i think none of them are optimized . and i'm sure there should be better way to do this
maybe this example be so easy but you consider More complicated situations

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you intend would really help.

Comment: abootorabi, do you try query?

Comment: yes , i try  the query you Recommend , and it worked thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
select a.* from
(select * from sport_table) a,
(select * from sport_table where id=1)b
where a.sport=b.sport and a.gender=b.gender and a.score>b.score
```